# Chaining localtime and mktime in jq

Tags: jq, localtime, mktime

If I do:

```
$ jq -cn 'now | localtime'
[2022,3,12,21,9,29.65448808670044,2,101]
```

It correctly gives the "broken down time" representation of current local time.

But If I do:

```
$ jq -cn 'now | localtime | mktime | localtime'
[2022,3,13,7,10,36,3,102]
```

It gives back a "broken down time" representation that is **different** than current local time.

I think when output of `localtime` is converted to seconds since unix epoch by `mktime` it is converted wrongly because it wrongly assumes GMT time?

If I do:

```
$ jq -cn 'now | gmtime | mktime | localtime'
```

Now this gives correct results (gives "broken down time" representation of current local time).

Am I correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

From the jq docs:

> The `mktime` builtin consumes "broken down time" representations of time output by `gmtime` and `strptime`.

You originally passed a local time, but it expects a UTC time. As you surmised, this is why your original code failed and the latter code worked. jq's `mktime` is the inverse of `gmtime`.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$ jq -rn 'now | ., ( gmtime | mktime )'
1649770973.430903
1649770973
```

jq does not appear to provide a means to convert from a local time to epoch time.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

1. This differs from the behaviour of C's `mktime`. C's `mktime` expects a local time, making it the inverse of `localtime`.
2. In C, `mktime` can serve both roles. While it normally converts from local time, it can also convert from UTC by setting the local time zone to UTC.